# VB.NET resource .designer include folder name. PublicResxFileCodeGenerator

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Using VS2019, in a VB.NET project I am trying to create 2 resource files with the same name, but in a different folder, and having both a different namespace.

When I do this in a C# project, the auto-generated .Designer.cs files will somewhere contain a line containing:

```cs
// /Dir1/Resource1.Designer.cs:
... new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("ConsoleApp2.Dir1.Resource1", typeof(Resource1).Assembly);

// Dir2/Resource1.Designer.cs:
... new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("ConsoleApp2.Dir2.Resource1", typeof(Resource1).Assembly);
```

Notice the Dir1 and Dir2 in the BaseName parameter.

However, when I try to do the same in a VB.NET project, the equivalent line looks like this for both of the files:

```vb
New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("ConsoleApp2.Resource1", GetType(Resource1).Assembly)
```

Notice how the directory name is not included in the BaseName parameter, thus giving an error when building:

> Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp2.Resource1.resources"

Trying to set the `ManifestResourceName` in the project file on the EmbeddedResource will resolve this build error but causes a `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` to be thrown at runtime.

Trying to set the `LogicalName` attribute in the project file on the EmbeddedResource did not make a difference.

Both of the files have the `Custom Tool` property set to: `PublicResxFileCodeGenerator`.

Both of the files have a different `Custom Tool Namespace` set.

So my question is, how can I get the PublicResxFileCodeGenerator tool to include the folder names in the generated .Designer files (in a VB.NET project)?